# Break in for dictionary loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, break

I have a function that loops through a JSON object.  The object often comes back in several different formats and I need to find a specific key and print the value of it.  Also, sometimes the key I need is listed multiple times.  So, I only want to print the first one.  I've tried using a break but it doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas why?

```
def deep(o):
    for k, v in o.iteritems():
        if k.lower() == 'key_i_look_for':
            print v
            break
        elif type(v) is dict:
            deep(o[k])
        elif type(v) is list:
            for i in v:
                if type(i) is dict:
                    deep(i)
```

Comment: `break` works just fine, so perhaps your input isn't exactly what you were expecting?

Comment: Are you ever planning on *returning* anything from your `deep()` function? Printing isn't much use for a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `break` works just fine, you are also recursing through a nested structure and never returning anything. You are ignoring the recursive searches in the outer calls; if one of them finds the key, the next recursive call is still executed.

You need to return recursive calls too, *and* take into account that some searches may not yield anything (return `None`):

```
def deep(o):
    for k, v in o.iteritems():
        if k.lower() == 'key_i_look_for':
            return v
        if not isinstance(v, list):
            v = [v]
        for i in v:
            if isinstance(i, dict):
                result = deep(i)
                if result is not None:
                    return result
```

I've cleaned up the logic a little to handle list vs. dictionary values a little easier, and switched to using `isinstance()` to allow for subclasses too.

This version *returns* the first key it finds; any recursive calls are checked for `None` to see if that recursive call turned up something, and break of the search there.

Comment: You can move the key lookup out of the loop: `if k.lower() in o: return o[k.lower()]`. If you do this, you can replace the for loop with `for v in o.values()`. I think it's clearer this way.

Comment: @RobertoBonvallet: no, you got the value to look for and the keys confused; if there is a key `'Key_I_Look_For'` for in the dictionary then `'key_i_look_for' in o` won't work.